# How to check if permuted hexadecimal integers matches to another using Bitwise operations (performance optimization)

Tags: java, android, algorithm, kotlin, bitwise-operators

After discussing a little about optimization of a part from my code in a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54428761/how-to-replace-this-string-operations-with-bitwise-operations) and getting some low-level improvements, @SergGr suggested me creating a new question to try get a high-level improvement and reach my main goal.

In my code I have to apply some moves in a "scrambled" [square-1 puzzle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square-1_(puzzle)) object and, after, check if it was solved. As I found a [better implementation of a square-1 puzzle object around internet](https://github.com/cs0x7f/sq12phase/blob/master/FullCube.java) I took it to be used in my Android application.

Then, as you can see, the [class](https://github.com/cs0x7f/sq12phase/blob/master/FullCube.java) is built with four simple numbers (`integer`) fields:

```
var ul = 0x011233
var ur = 0x455677 //continuation of ul

var dl = 0x998bba
var dr = 0xddcffe //continuation of dl
```

These fields means the "pieces" of the square-1 puzzle, where each digit in the `hexadecimal` representation is one of these pieces (double digits such as `11`, `33`, `bb`... means the same "piece" of the cube, which is a "big" piece).

As you can see, some operations which represents real actions through the puzzle are made using that numbers, but at the most is permutations through its bits.

In the case of my application I have to check if the puzzle is solved but, for my situation, the solved state is not, necessarily, equals to the raw fields. As we talking about a Rubik's Cube variant the faces could be moved, the we can have a solved state like (ul + " " + ur): `[112334 556770]`, `[233455 677011]`, `[455677 11233*]` and so on.

*Obs.: note to leading zero...*

Then I thought a simple algorithm to check the solved state by looking for cyclic permutations in a fixed solved sequence, but using `Strings`. However, after some tests I realized that this work, using `Strings` as I did, was making my app still so slow, once I have to call this checking thousand times in a big loop.

## Quick explanation about my algorithm using Strings:

- Convert all numbers to `String` (in this case a hex String);
- A fixed solved state (`ul+ur`): `s = "011233"+"455677"`;
- A state to check if is solved (`ul+ur`): `t = "233455"+"677011"`;
- If we concat `s+s` we check if we can found `t` inside: `"011{233455677011}233455677"`, then `isSolved()` checking returns `true`.

## Where I have to apply this

Basically the core code of my app is this and I check if the puzzle is solved like this:

```
for (sequence in sequences) { //814*814 elements
    auxCube.applySequence(sequence.seq) //applies the current sequence to the auxiliary cube
    if (auxCube.isSolved()) { //checks if it was solved
        searches.add(Search(sequence.seq)) //adds the success in a list
    }
    auxCube.copy(oldCube) //back test cube to initial state to continue finding sequences
}
```

As you can see, there are only 2 functions made by me being used here. I'll describe the method `applySequence()` below.

## The `applySequence()` method

I made this method by myself to apply formatted sequences to the square-1 puzzle object. Once official sequences for this puzzle are composed by some characters (looks like: "`(1, 2) / (6, -3) /`" I did some steps to extract the numbers and, after, move the cube. It looks like:

```
fun applySequence(sequence: String) {
    //remove all "(", ")", "," and " " characters and split in each "/"
    val pairs = sequence.replace(" ", "").replace("\\(", "").replace("\\)", "").split("/")

    //if starts with / then perform respective move
    if (sequence.startsWith("/")) slashMove()

   //iterate over pairs
    for (pair in pairs) {
        //checks if pair is not empty
        if (pair != "") {
            //split pair in the "," character
            val pairMoves = pair.split(",")
            
            //perform top and bottom moves with extracted numbers
            move(true, Integer.parseInt(pairMoves[0]))
            move(false, Integer.parseInt(pairMoves[1]))
            slashMove()
        }
    }

    //if sequence not ends with / then applies respective move
    if (!sequence.endsWith("/")) slashMove()
}
```

---

This way is so simple but considering it uses `String` operations like `concat()` and `contains()` in a for that loops over 600000 times the performance, in Android, is reduced.

After trying optimize I realized that one the best ways to do it comes with bitwise operations, operations such the author did over his original code, however I couldn't figure it out.

As a extra info about the problem, if I remove the call of my `isSolved()` method the final time of the search reduces in `20~30 seconds`.

Then, how to perform `isSolved()` operation using bitewising to work lighter in a big for loop (targeting Android)?

Comment: This is not really a higher level problem I meant. What your application does? Does it solves the puzzle automatically or let the user to solve it? In the latter case the performance of `isSolved` is irrelevant because you only need to call it once per user action and humans are not that fast. If you do automatic solving, then show us the algorithm you use to solve it. This is the higher level problem. It might be easier to make the code faster by checking less combinations than by doing `isSolved` faster. To sum up: put your `isSolved` into your real context that shows why it should be fast.

Comment: My code searches for solutions based in a predefined database sequences. I have some sequences saved and I test it all to check what solves the scrambled puzzle. Basically the structure of this search is: put the cube to searchable state -> iterate over sequences -> checks is the puzzle was solved -> continue the search. Is valid to know that my goal is not solve the entire puzzle, but only a single step and, for this reason, I really need use specifically the saved sequences. I'll update the question with a view of the structure I said and with the view of the method I use to apply a seq.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if two values are cyclic shift of each other with bitwise operations.

Your values are 6-byte (48 bits length) values, so we can pack them in 64-bit `long`, then make cyclic rotation of low 48 bits for one value and check for coincidence with other one.

[Ideone](https://ideone.com/ghaU50)

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        long a = (0x011233l) << 24 | 0x455677;
        long b = (0x233455l) << 24 | 0x677011;
        System.out.printf("a: %x   b: %x  \n", a, b);
        if (b == a)
            System.out.printf(" bingo at zero digits shift \n");

        for (int sh=4; sh<48; sh+=4) {
            long bb = (b >> sh)|((b << (64 - sh))>>16); 
            System.out.printf("rotated %d bits  bb: %x \n", sh, bb);
            if (bb == a)
                System.out.printf(" bingo at %d digits shift \n", sh/4);
        }
    }
}

a: 11233455677   b: 233455677011  
rotated 4 bits  bb: 123345567701 
rotated 8 bits  bb: 112334556770 
rotated 12 bits  bb: 11233455677 
  bingo at 3 digits shift 
rotated 16 bits  bb: 701123345567 
skipped
rotated 44 bits  bb: 334556770112
```